# CF table skipping rows when creating table

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am using MS SQL Server 2014 and Coldfusion 10 and am running into an issue posting on my table. My Associate Total for some users on my table is getting skipped over when the pdf is created. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong that would make the Associate Total field just get skipped over for a couple users?

```
<cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
<cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

<!--- WHITELIST OF VALID LOCATIONS --->
    <cfset validLocs = "OPERATIONS, CCC, QA, DS, PS, LWR, NR, SDL, FSC">
    <cfset locList = "">
    <cfif structKeyExists(FORM,"location") AND len(FORM.location) GT 0>
        <cfloop list="#FORM.location#" index="vLoc"> 
            <cfif listContainsNoCase(validLocs, vLoc) GT 0> 
            <cfset locList = listAppend(locList,vloc)>
            </cfif> 
        </cfloop> 
    <cfelse>
    </cfif>


<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo">
    SELECT * 
      FROM ( 
        SELECT t1.associate 
        , a.assoc_name 
        , t1.trans_location 
        , t1.checklistsByAssocLoc 
        , t1.totalChecklistsByAssoc 
        , CASE WHEN ( coalesce(t1.totalChecklistsByAssoc,0) > 0 ) THEN (CAST(t1.checklistsByAssocLoc AS decimal(8,2))/t1.totalChecklistsByAssoc) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS totalChecklistsByAssocLocPct /* This gives you a percent of associate location checklists over count of checklists by Associate */ , t1.totalChecklistsByLoc 
        , CASE WHEN ( coalesce(t1.totalChecklistsByLoc,0) > 0 ) THEN (CAST(t1.checklistsByAssocLoc AS decimal(8,2))/t1.totalChecklistsByLoc) * 100 ELSE 0 END AS totalChecklistsByLocPct /* This gives you a percent of associate location checklists over count of checklists by Location */ 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY associate ORDER BY associate, trans_location) AS rnA 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY associate, trans_location ORDER BY trans_location) AS rnL 
        , t1.rnTotAssoc 
      FROM ( 
        SELECT c.associate 
        , c.trans_location 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.associate, c.trans_location) AS checklistsByAssocLoc /* Gives you a count of checklists by Associate and Location >> I think this is 1.1 locCntr */ 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.associate) AS totalChecklistsByAssoc /* Gives you a count of checklists by Associate */ 
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.trans_location) AS totalChecklistsByLoc /* Gives you a count of checklists by Location */ 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.associate ORDER BY c.trans_location DESC) AS rnTotAssoc 
      FROM cl_checklists c 
      WHERE c.[DATE] >= <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" /> 
        AND c.[DATE] <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" /> 
        AND c.trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#locList#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
      ) t1 
        INNER JOIN tco_associates a ON t1.associate = a.assoc_id 
      ) s2 
      WHERE s2.rnA = 1 OR s2.rnL = 1 
      ORDER BY s2.assoc_name, s2.trans_location 
</cfquery>  

<cfif GetEmployeeInfo.recordcount is 0>

<td width="85%" valign="top" class="mainmodule"><p class="pageheader">CHECKLIST STATS REPORT</p><br />
    No matching records found
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<cfelse>

<cfif FORM.Format IS "print">

<cfdocument format="pdf" scale="75" backgroundvisible="yes" overwrite="no" fontembed="yes">

<td width="85%" valign="top" class="mainmodule"><p class="pageheader">CHECKLIST STATS REPORT</p><br />

<style type="text/css">
    table{
      text-align:center;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Associate Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Associate</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s)</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Associate Percentage of Location Total</strong></th>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfoutput query="GetEmployeeInfo">
      <tr>
          <td><cfif rnA EQ 1><strong>#assoc_name#</strong></cfif></td>
          <td><cfif rnL EQ 1>#trans_location#</cfif></td>
          <td>#checklistsByAssocLoc#</td>
          <td>#totalChecklistsByLoc#</td>
          <td>#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %</td>
      </tr>
      <cfif rnTotAssoc EQ 1> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Associate Total</td> 
          <td></td> 
          <td>#totalChecklistsByAssoc#</td> 
          <td>#totalChecklistsByLoc#</td> 
          <td>#DecimalFormat(totalChecklistsByLocPct)# %</td> 
      </tr>
      </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>

</cfdocument>

</cfif>

</cfif>
```

Results should look like:

```
Brierton, David SDL 1 32195 0.00 % 
Associate Total     1 32195 0.00 %
```

Some are showing as just:

```
Brierton, David SDL 1 32195 0.00 %
```

Comment: What is `rnTotAssoc` equal to in those cases?

Comment: it is equal to 1

Comment: well the ones that work are equal to 1 the others do not show so I dont know what there equal to

Comment: i@Miguel-F is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't know your data. I was just trying to point out the reason why some rows are not displaying. It's up to you to decide whether that condition is appropriate or not.

Comment: yea i dont get it the numbers are so random the majority are ones but then the others are such random numbers like 514, 112 , 254, 2269

Comment: And the numbers dont stay the same when you rerun it

Comment: so confusing. Is there a better way I should be trying to add the associate total?

Comment: If your long complex query is giving bad results, run something much shorter and simpler.  Once that starts giving good results add one more bit and test again.  Repeat until done.

Comment: The query itself is pretty short, it's just using a lot of window functions to keep track of which records are which in the query. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The last 3 columns are only placeholders. The only number that matters in them is a 1. For every Associate in the filter, there should be at least one row in rnA with a 1, and one row with rnL and rnTotAssoc with 1s, but they both may be the same row. Those numbers are only used to show a display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query looks correct.

rnA = 1 will give rows that include the first instance of an Associate Name.

rnL = 1 will give rows for the first instance of the Location.

rnTotAssoc = 1 will give the final row of an associate, including their Locations. The next row should display a total of the Associates records. Every Associate should have at least 1 record with rnTotAssoc = 1.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56892/10

Do you have bad data that's messing up the results? Try singling out one or two people and coming up with what should be their correct counts. You can remove `WHERE s2.rnA = 1 OR s2.rnL = 1` from the query to see all rows that are going into those counts.

Comment: As long as one row is 1 for rnA, rnL and rnTotAssoc, it shouldn't matter. If that number isn't 1, then SQL sorted it in a different order to generate that number.

Comment: Take the Associate whose record didn't show and specifically look up that Associate in the query. See what rows are available for that Associate. Change WHERE to `WHERE s2.assoc_name = '<Associate Name>' or s2.associate = <Associate ID>`.